# What exactly is low bits subtraction

Tags: c, micro-optimization, guile

I was reading [this article](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Cheaper-Pairs.html#Cheaper-Pairs) and thought that that everything was perfectly clear until I stumble upon this:

> Again, most real Scheme systems use a slightly different implementation; for example, if `GET_PAIR` subtracts off the low bits of `x`, instead of masking them off, the optimizer will often be able to combine that subtraction with the addition of the offset of the structure member we are referencing, making a modified pointer as fast to use as an unmodified pointer.

How exactly one can achieve this subtraction and how the optimizer will do its magic to modify the pointer as fast as unmodified pointer?

Comment: Using `-` instead of `&`??

Comment: This is not about C or C++. Neither are bitshifts. Don't spam tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick presented in the article is to encode type information into the unused three lowest bits of an 8 byte aligned pointer. After using this information to find out the type,

```c
#define PAIR_P(x) (((int) (x) & 7) == 2)
```

one has to clear those additional bits before using the pointer as an address again.

```c
#define GET_PAIR(x) ((struct pair *) ((int) (x) & ~7))
```

Note that at this point, we already know the type, so we know the value of the three least significant bits. They will always be `0b010` (decimal 2). So, instead of writing `((int) (x) & ~7)`, the author suggests to rather write `((int) (x) - 2)`. The idea is that if you write code like this,

```c
if (PAIR_P(x))
  {
    SCM * thing = GET_PAIR(x)->cdr;
    /* Use the thing… */
  }
```

because we are accessing the `cdr` member inside the `struct pair` pointed to by the `x` (after clearing out the lower bits), the compiler will generate code to adjust the pointer appropriately. Something like this.

```c
SCM * thing = (SCM *) ((char *)((int) (x) - 2)) + offsetof(struct pair, cdr));
```

Thanks to the associativity of integer addition and subtraction, we can omit one level of parenthesis and get (not showing the outer pointer casts that produce no machine code anyway)

```c
(int) (x) - 2 + offsetof(struct pair, cdr)
```

where both, the `2` and the `offsetof(struct pair, cdr)` are compile-time constants and can be folded into a single constant. If we had asked for the `car` member (which has offset 0), this trick wouldn't help, but helping every other time is not too bad.

A modern optimizer might be able to figure out by itself that after we've just tested that `(x & 7) == 2`, `x & ~7` is equivalent to `x - 2` so the trick might not be required any more these days. You would like to measure this before you rely on it, though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I haven't thought about the structure offsets.. now I understand. Thank you again!